# How to create two macOS Installations on one iMac, securely separated from each other by using FileVault?

Tags: partition, security, filevault, dual-boot, administrator

The requirement in a no-budget project is as follows: an existing iMac, which is used by one developer for most of the time, has to be used by a second developer from time to time; so both developers need their own admin accounts (with full root permissions). But since **none of the admins should be able to *read* the other's data**, creating two admin accounts isn't a solution.

Therefore I consider to split the drive into 2 partitions and installing macOS into each of them, then creating one admin account per macOS partition and securing them by separate FileVaults (I know that each admin could delete the whole partition of the other, but that's not a problem in this context).

These questions occur:

1. Which filesystem/format should I use for the two partitions?
2. The iMac has a 1TB Fusion Drive: what do I have to take into consideration?
3. Since both systems will have the same software installed: is it possible to create a 3rd partition that holds the application folder for both macOS systems?

Looking forward for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on your questions (and one other):

1. Which filesystem/format should I use for the two partitions?

Assuming a recent version of macOS, use APFS. You don't have any choice.

2. The iMac has a 1TB Fusion Drive: what do I have to take into consideration?

Ouch! One partition will combine the SSD with part of the HDD, the other will be HDD only. So one of the developers will have a slow HDD only system.

This really makes the two partition model a bad way of separating your two developers.

3. Since both systems will have the same software installed: is it possible to create a 3rd partition that holds the application folder for both macOS systems?

You can't move the whole /Applications to a third partition. Some applications could be installed to a third partition. Some applications must be in /Applications. And Apple are making what you propose more difficult by relocating applications not in /Applications.

I would have a third partition for shared things, but not to partially replace /Applications or other system folders.

4. Are there any alternatives? Yes, but they destroy your zero-budget project.

4A. Each developer (or maybe just the 'other' developer) could have their own external SSD and boot from that.

4B. Replace the HDD with a large SSD and using that in place of the Fusion Drive. You could make that into 2 (or 3) partitions. What is possible depends on the model of iMac.

Comment: A fusion drive is basically a logical partition spanning both the SSD and the HDD. In a multi-partition approach as required for account separation wouldn’t one users end up with a small Fusion Drive and the other with a pure HDD partition?

Comment: On reflection, my answer is wrong! I will change it.